# R: Create multiple matrices per sets of equal specific elements from df with volumes as main var

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, matrix, iteration

Say [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXSTa.png) is a sample of a bigger df which essentially shows multiple characteristics per volume.

I would like to make a matrix for every equal combination of Date, Day of Week, Node ID and Volume Type. So on Wednesday 2017-08-09 where the Node was X1 and the Volume Type was A1, a matrix would be made with such parameters and the Countdown and Volumes.

In this case the matrix would look like:

```
-72 2017-08-09  Wednesday   X1  A1  500
-60 2017-08-09  Wednesday   X1  A1  1000
```

...but the idea is that it will be obviously much bigger.

To further explain, say all the parameters were the same, except for the Volume Type which would be A2. In this case a new matrix would take place for all rows that had the same parameters. And on and on.

Essentially, every time a certain row fulfills any combination of Date, Dow, Node ID and Volume Type, put everything from that row in a matrix where all other rows that have the exact same criteria go to.

Thanks for the aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the `split` function. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(day=c('mon','mon','mon','tue','tue','tue','wed'),type=c('A','A','A','B','B','A','C'),value=c(3,1,1,2,1,2,1))
```

Let's say we want to group all rows where the column `day` and `type` are equal. We first create an array which we can use to group the values, and then split according to this value:

```
library(dplyr)
group_id <- df %>% group_indices(day,type) # Or in your case: Date, Dow, Node ID and Volume Type
split(df,group_id)
```

The result looks as follows:

```
$`1`
  day type value
1 mon    A     3
2 mon    A     1
3 mon    A     1

$`2`
  day type value
6 tue    A     2

$`3`
  day type value
4 tue    B     2
5 tue    B     1

$`4`
  day type value
7 wed    C     1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also, how can I order everyone of those tables by, in my case, the Countdown column values and then turn every table into a matrix?

Comment: You could sort your dataframe beforehand with `order(x,y)`. I dont think you can make a matrix, because then the values ened to be the same class (e.g. numeric, character, etc).